# connect to an outside mongodb from MS Access

Tags: vba, mongodb, ms-access

There is a similar thread and I like one of the answers there, the one using shell. But it seems to connect to a running instance of mongo.

In my case, there's no running instance, the Mongo db is somewhere else and I can't figure out how to connect to it using this script.
I guess i would need a way to add a connection string to an outside MongoDB using an approach similar to the one below.

[How to connect Mongodb from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008598/how-to-connect-mongodb-from-excel/37076463)

This is the answer

> The Shell Approach
> Pretty much anything that interfaces with the Command Line can be accessed with Shell.

Here's a bare-bones example that connects to a running MongoDB instance and prints a query to the Immediate Window. You'll need to add a reference to the Windows Script Host Object Model.

```vb
Private Sub Test()

    Dim wsh As New WshShell
    Dim proc As WshExec
    Dim line As String
    
    Set proc = wsh.Exec("mongo")
    
    With proc
        .StdIn.WriteLine "use test"
        .StdIn.WriteLine "db.restaurants.find({""address.zipcode"":""10075""})"
        .StdIn.WriteLine "quit()"
        
        Do While .Status = WshRunning
            line = .StdOut.ReadLine
            If line = "Type ""it"" for more" Then
                .StdIn.WriteLine "it"
            ElseIf line Like "{*" Then
                Debug.Print line
            End If
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Just printing the raw JSON strings isn't very exciting or useful, however. You could write your own JSON parser but, for this example, we will use VBA-JSON by Tim Hall (you can find it on GitHub).

At the time of writing, there is one issue with VBA-JSON that has to be tackled when using it to parse strings returned from MongoDB. Any values that contain parentheses, e.g. `"_id": ObjectId("...")`, will throw an error. A quick and dirty fix for this is to use RegEx to clean the string for the parser. You will need to reference the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 library for the following function to work.

```vb
Private Function CleanString(str As String) As String

    Dim temp As String
    Dim rx As New RegExp
    
    With rx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        
        .Pattern = "[a-z]*\(" ' Left
        temp = .Replace(str, "")
        .Pattern = "\)" ' Right
        temp = .Replace(temp, "")
    End With
    
    CleanString = temp
End Function
```

We can then parse the JSON returned from MongoDB and add each object to a Collection. Accessing the values becomes quite simple.

```vb
Private Sub Mongo()

    Dim wsh As New WshShell
    Dim proc As WshExec
    Dim line As String
    Dim response As New Collection
    Dim json As Object
    
    Set proc = wsh.Exec("mongo")
    
    With proc
        .StdIn.WriteLine "use test"
        .StdIn.WriteLine "db.restaurants.find({""address.zipcode"":""10075""})"
        .StdIn.WriteLine "quit()"
        
        Do While .Status = WshRunning
            line = .StdOut.ReadLine
            If line = "Type ""it"" for more" Then
                .StdIn.WriteLine "it"
            ElseIf line Like "{*" Then
                response.Add ParseJson(CleanString(line))
            End If
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With
    
    For Each json In response
        Debug.Print json("name"), json("address")("street")
    Next
End Sub
```

... Which will produce the following output from the MongoDB Example Dataset.

```
Nectar Coffee Shop          Madison Avenue
Viand Cafe                  Madison Avenue
Don Filippo Restaurant      Lexington Avenue
Lusardi'S Restaurant        Second Avenue
Due                         Third Avenue
Lenox Hill Grill/Pizza      Lexington Avenue
Quatorze Bistro             East   79 Street
Luke'S Bar & Grill          Third Avenue
Starbucks Coffee            Lexington Avenue
New York Jr. League         East   80 Street
Doc Watsons                 2 Avenue
Serafina Fabulous Pizza     Madison Avenue
Canyon Road Grill           1 Avenue
Sushi Of Gari East          78 Street
```

Gotchas

`ReadLine` and `WriteLine` are blocking functions.
The window opened by `Exec` can't be hidden.
A workaround for both of the above would be to use a two-layer approach, where VBA calls a hidden script using `wsh.Run`, which then runs the `Exec` (as well as any other code that interacts with the proc). The downside to this approach is that `StdIn` (and to an extent `StdOut`) has to be written to a file.

Comment: This reads like an informational post. Please make your specific question prominent for readers.

Comment: how else can i make it prominent? it's in the first paragraph, i need to know how to connect to outside MongoDB using a similar approach

Comment: Oh, I see. And I notice you copied most of the answer to linked post nearly word for word. Maybe just reference and keep the first paragraph?

Comment: Outside of Access how do you connect to that remote MongoDB? Do you use a specific command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to an external MongoDB, simply adjust the Windows Shell call to point to external address. Per [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/mongo/#local-mongodb-instance-on-default-port), `mongo` by itself defaults to localhost at port 27017. For a remote host, adjust these defaults.

Using connection string:

```vb
Set proc = wsh.Exec("mongo ""mongodb://username:password@host:port/database""")
```

Using [args](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/reference/options/#std-option-mongosh.--help):

```vb
Set proc = wsh.Exec("mongo --host <server_or_ip_address>" _
                  & "      --port <port_number>" _
                  & "      --username <username>" _
                  & "      --password <password>")
```

Above would require having the `mongo` shell installed on client machine even with no database set up locally. Also, the server machine hosting the MongoDB must allow external connections. Read docs for setup and instructions.

Comment: thank you very much! i'm getting an error. heres my connection string Set proc = wsh.Exec("mongo ""mongodb://myusername:mypassword@servername:portnumber/dbname"""). and i'm getting "method exec of object iwshshell3 failed"

Comment: Can you test command in your mongo shell first (outside of VBA) with CMD or PowerShell? One thought is `mongo` needs to be a recognized command so the folder of its .exe should be in `PATH` environment folder.